# Is it possible to create a new model in RNetLogo or change the source code of sample models?

Tags: r, netlogo

I am pretty new to the RNetLogo package in R, but so far all the examples of using RNetLogo I saw were about loading model samples and doing something with them. I did not see any examples which show that we can create our own model and write down rules according to which our agents will interact with each other (or see the code of sample models and change it). Is it possible to write these rules in R or does RNetLogo allow us to play with already implemented models (samples) only without changing the code?

For example, when we open in NetLogo Models Library-->Earth Science-->Climate Change (just random example) then we can go to the Code tab and see the code written in NetLogo prog.language:

```
globals [ 
  sky-top      ;; y coordinate of top row of sky 
...
```

My question is: can we see this code in R and change it?

Answer (score 0):

My answer, I do not think so :-) . You need to developpe your model in netlogo and with RNetlogo in R you can run it, play with data, send some data.frame to your model, change some variable.